# Auto update document copies on check in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, document-library, document

We all are aware of Send To Functionality of Document Libraries as explained here http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/copy-a-file-to-another-library-or-send-to-location-HA101782473.aspx#_Toc259088285

As mentioned on the link shared, we need to update the changes in the copies manually.

What i need is whenever someone update the the file and checkin, the copies should get updated automatically.

Could someone please suggest something to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with an Event Receiver attached to the source library.
So, whenever a document is edited, you can use the [SPCopyDestinationCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcopydestination_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to detect if the file has any copy linked to it. If it has, you'll want to use the method `SPListItem.CopyTo` to copy the updated document to all its destination copies.